# How to design schemaless models for MongoDB in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Client and a WebApi. The Client wants to store some complex data in a MongoDB behind the WebApi. While the Client needs to know the whole schema of the data the WebApi doesn't.

Imagine the Client needs objects like:

```
{
  "id": "123abc",
  "context": "work",
  
  "one": 1,
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "c": "c"
  }
}
```

Imagine the WebApi needs only to operate on the properties `id` and `context` to filter.

How should I design the model in C#? Is there a way to define something like a Dictionary<string, object?> with required fields?

```
/// THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK!!!!!
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MyModel : Dictionary<string, object?> {

  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
  public string id { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("context")]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "context")]
  public string? context { get; set; }
  
  /*
  The properties "one", "a", "b", "b.c" should 
  get saved and loaded. But I do not want to
  list them explicitly in this model.
  */
}
```

Is there a pattern to simplyfy the models? To handle them a bit more schemaless?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using 2 different models for this case. But answering on your question, you should use `BsonExtraElements` attribute, something like:

```
public class MyModel 

  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
  public string id { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("context")]
  public string? context { get; set; }
  
  /*
  The properties "one", "a", "b", "b.c" should 
  get saved and loaded. But I do not want to
  list them explicitly in this model.
  */
  
  [BsonExtraElements]
  public Dictionary<string, object> ExtraElements { get; set; }
  
  // or a bit more mongo like:
  //[BsonExtraElements]
  //public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }  
}
```